# How to read a text file of dictionary to dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a text file whose body is the followingm(line by line):

```
{"Age":"23", "Gender": "M", "Salary": "2300"}
{"Age":"31", "Gender": "F", "Salary": "3300"}
{"Age":"27", "Gender": "M", "Salary": "2600"}
{"Age":"43", "Gender": "F", "Salary": "5300"}
```

Suppose this text file is `Age.txt`. I would like to read this textfile as a `pandas` dataframe so that the output would be:

```
"Age"  "Gender"  "Salary"
 23      "M"      2300
 31      "F"      3300
 27      "M"      2600
 43      "F"      5300
```

How would I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.read_json` with `lines=True`:

```py
df = pd.read_json("your_file.txt", lines=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Age Gender  Salary
0   23      M    2300
1   31      F    3300
2   27      M    2600
3   43      F    5300
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(map(eval,f.read().splitlines()))
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
   Age Gender  Salary
0   23      M    2300
1   31      F    3300
2   27      M    2600
3   43      F    5300
```